# How to resolve connection refused when Jenkin in Docker connect to Docker Daemon?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to run the [pipeline example of python](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/#python).

[image]

I am able to start Jenkins in Docker and connect to Git but I get "docker not found" error when trigger the job:

```
+ docker inspect -f . python:3.5.1
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/example-project@tmp/durable-6edc6c68/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/example-project@tmp/durable-6edc6c68/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull python:3.5.1
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/example-project@tmp/durable-bd8f56f3/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/example-project@tmp/durable-bd8f56f3/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
```

I have also referred to other online solution by adding Docker to be install automatically in Global Tool Configuration:

[image]

However, my Jenkins in Docker container is unable to connect to Docker Daemon when I configure the Docker plugin

[image]

On the other hand, my another Jenkins that is installed in Window 10 is able to connect to Docker Daemon. Therefore, may I know what can goes wrong?

Comment: Is docker installed on the executors ?

Comment: Hello @abhishekphukan, what do you mean "docker installed on the executors"? I have installed docker plugin in Jenkins